# How to Smooth the Tracking in CamShift

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, kalman-filter

I'm Doing Project on hand Tracking using OpenCV library function. By using `Camshift()` function I could able to track my hands but it wasn't not stable, even I make my hand stable there is little movement in tracking. So I couldn't able to perform mouse click operation at correct position. Someone please help me to figure out this.

```
void TrackingObjects::drawRectangle(CvRect objectLocation){
CvPoint p1, p2,mou;
CvRect crop;
p1.x = objectLocation.x;
p2.x = objectLocation.x + objectLocation.width;

p1.y = objectLocation.y;
p2.y = objectLocation.y + objectLocation.height;

cvRectangle(image,p1,p2,CV_RGB(0,255,0),1,CV_AA,0);

mou.x=(p2.x-p1.x)/2;
mou.x=p1.x+mou.x;
mou.y=(p2.y-p1.y)/2;
mou.y=p1.y+mou.y;

SetCursorPos(mou.x,mou.y);

}
```

In above code I get the tracked object location by `obectLocation` parameter and I've drawn rectangle over the tracked region.
By getting its center I did mouse movement.

While closing the palm in order to do `MouseDown` event, the position of tracked object has being changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is Kalman filters.
You can use [this](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/06/17/simple-kalman-filter-for-tracking-using-opencv-2-2-w-code/) code. As you can see in the figure below, the filtered results (green line) ignore tracker's sudden displacements (where cyan depicts the original tracking results).

[image]