# How filtering the detected face position and size along time?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, face-detection, core-image

I created an app that uses Core Image (CIDetector, CIDetectorTypeFace) for face detection (tracking) in realtime. Something similar to:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_XiwtoorLk
I wonder how can I filter the face position and size in order to have something smooth.
I guess I have to use a low pass or high pass filter, but not sure how can I do it.
Does anyone have an idea or recommendation?
I saw an app doing something like that, but I don't remember it.
Thanks for help.

EDIT: When I say filtering, this is what I mean:
Left: What I receive from core image when a face is detected.
Right: The filtered signal from the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look more into object tracking in general. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678585/how-to-smooth-the-tracking-in-camshift) post suggests using Kalman filters, which may be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for, although it's a bit difficult. A low pass filter perhaps could also do the trick.